# Initial post to external email address in Google Groups for Business

Tags: google-groups

Ok, so I've set up a Collaborative Inbox on Google Groups for Business. It looks good so far, but one thing I can't seem to figure out:

I would like to use it for career@mycompany.com, and one of the biggest use cases would be to start a thread by writing email to a potential candidate. I tried to send email from Gmail, using "send as", to an external address - this doesn't open a thread in the group. Then I sent an email to an external address CCing of BCCing career@mycompany.com - this opens a new thread, but the message comes from career@ and shows no sign of the external email, which seems obvious.

Within the group, I don't seem to be able to start a new thread that initially goes to an external email.

Is there a way to do this use case with Google Groups for Business / Collaborative Inbox?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

There is no way to add an address to the TO field from the web UI of Google Groups.

## Alternatives

One alternative is to include the recipient in CC

Another alternative is to send the email from an "individual" email account  and

- add the group email address to the Reply-to field
- add the group email address to the TO OR CC fields and tell the recipient to use Reply-to-all

## References

- [Use a group as a collaborative inbox - Google Apps Administrator Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430?hl=en)
- [Create a topic - Groups Help](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1046523?hl=en&ref_topic=2458614)
- [Setting the reply-to address - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7991?hl=en)